# Define this recursively : $f(n) = 3n - 4$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursion

Define this recursively : $f(n) = 3n - 4$

I thought this is how you recursively define a function?

$f^{-1}(n): y = 3n-4$

$y+4 = 3n$

$f^{-1}(n) = (y+4/3)$

But the answer is $f(n) = f(n-1) + B$

What've I done and what should I've done?

Comment: It's worth saying that you seem to have mixed up finding the _inverse_ (which is what you've done) with finding a _recursion_ (which defines $f(n+1)$ in terms of $f(n)$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have found the inverse of the function, $f^{-1}(n)$, this is a function which has the property:

$$f^{-1}(f(n))=f(f^{-1}(n))=n \qquad \forall n\in D$$

Where $D$ is the domain of $f$. What the question is asking is for an equivalent definition of $f(n)$ using values of $f(m)$ where $m<n$. In this case we can examine what happens for small values of $n$:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline n & 1  & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\ \hline
f(n) &-1 & 2 & 5 & 8 & 11 & 14  \\ \hline
\end{array}

This suggests that we can write our recurrence relationship as: $f(1)=-1$ and:

$$f(n)=f(n-1)+3$$

Comment: How do you get the $+3$ from?

Comment: Is it because $f(n-1) = 3n-7$ and you get the difference between $f(n) and f(n-1)$?

Answer (score 0):

$$f(n)= 3n-4$$ 
$$f(n+1)= 3(n+1)-4=3n+3-4=3n-4+3=f(n)+3$$

Comment: $3(n+1)-4 = 3n + 3 - 4 = 3n - 1$

Comment: @user3650172 Yes, but we're trying to get $3n -4$ in there somehow, so we can swap that for $f(n)$, because that's what a recursive definition means: that one term is defined by earlier terms.